# Theme upload on a child Wordpress Multisite

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm using this plugin that enables to "Add Plugin" from a child Wordpress Multisite.

https://github.com/bueltge/WordPress-Multisite-Enhancements

Is there an equivalent plugin or hack for adding themes as a Wordpress Multisite site user and not only as the super-user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to do so on Wordpress Multisite, at least in WP 3.x